# calculate singular vector from eigen-decomposition for symmetric matrix

Tags: svd, eigenvector

For some reason, I need to calculate singular vectors V in the singular value decomposition A = U Sigma V^T, using eigendecomposition, where A is a symmetric matrix.

I think for a symmetric matrix, the singular vector is the same as the eigenvector subject to the sign of eigenvalues.

So calculating singular vector from eigendecomposition we need to correct this sign issue. I saw someone using QR decomposition on their eigenvectors and the Q matrix will be the orthogonal matrix that equals the singular vectors.

Can someone explain to me why QR factorization will correct this sign difference between eigenvectors and singular vectors for the symmetric matrix?

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Comment: If so, then please show your code. If not, then please delete and post on https://math.stackexchange.com/.